# UIImagePickerController - picking video in background from photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

How to continue picking video from photo library in background mode ?

I mean when I press `use` button from `imagePickerController - PhotoLibrary` and video is started to get compressing - During this compression process (have attached screenshot) if I press `home button(i.e. go to background)` and then come to `foreground` then I got `info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` as `null`, so is it possible that app can continue compressing video in background also and return proper `url` when come to `foreground` ?

Screenshot :

[image]

My `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`,

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{


NSURL *url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSLog(@"url : %@",url);

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

P.S : If we record video by `camera` and go to background then it will stop recording there and we can use it after coming foreground.

I have thought of one workaround - `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` but it will not work in every case, if video is big then it have time limit, so looking for any other solution!

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF we want to pick `video` continuously in background by `UIImagePickerController` from `photolibrary` during `video is compressing and user press home button(app go in background)` then we have to use `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` for continue execution in background or any other background way which keeps app working in background(less possible thing!). Now, `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` has time limit so we can't pick any size of video, so if we restricted video time duration then we can pick it continuously in background something like,

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0;

 self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

            self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                NSLog(@"Background handler called. Not running background tasks anymore.");
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
                self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

With `UIImagePickerController` we can do that much only to pick video in background. If anyone want to pick large video in background then he/she should take look into `ALAssetLibrary` or `Photos framework`.